# Using ternary operator instead of if/else in javascript

Tags: javascript

Say you have a simple array with random numbers, given the following code, how would i reduce the line of code to use a ternary operator to render the following.

> [1, 2, 1, 4, 6]

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 15];

let myArray = arr.map((val, i, arr) => {
  if (val % 2 === 0) {
    return val
  } else {
    return val % 2
  }
});

console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Oops, not a dupe, you're using `return val % 2`, not `val * 2` (though it's exactly the same in all other respects)

Comment: so many good answers, but i can only pick one. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the ternary condition as a single liner:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,13,15];

const myArray = arr.map((val) => val % 2 === 0 ? val: val % 2);

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Good answer. Just imho  :  You can use `const` instead of `let` as you are not reassigning the `arr` nor the `myArray` . Also why add `i` and `arr` in the map if you are not using them ? also `arr` is used before so you shouldn't use 'shadow' naming.

Comment: I like this answer the most

Comment: @randal glad to help

Answer (score 3):

Logical OR can do the trick for you.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,13,15]

let myArray = arr.map((val) => val % 2 || val);

console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [bitwise AND `&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND) or (with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_())) the value, instead of a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Bitwise AND with a value of one returns either one or zero, depending on the other operand.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 15],
    result = array.map(v => v & 1 || v);

console.log(result);
```